# How to render component from React Route to a different div than root

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I have an App main component with react router:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/screenings" exact component={SPT} />
        <Route path="/registerpage" exact component={RegisterPage} />
        <Route path="/loginpage" exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/logout" exact component={LoginPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

In main index.js I render that component:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Currently when I click on any link in navigation `bar/route` component linked in router is rendered right below the navigation bar in `root` div element. However I would like to render those components to `mainpage` div that is set below `root` div so navbar and rest of the page is clearly separated (placed in 2 different divs). Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say it would be impossible to get the content in `mainpage` if that element is below the `root` element, but you would make it unnecessarily hard that way.

If the situation is just that you want to separate them into two different divs why don't you just wrap your switch in a div? That way every route will be rendered in the `<div id='mainpage'>` element.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <div id='mainpage'>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/screenings" exact component={SPT} />
          <Route path="/registerpage" exact component={RegisterPage} />
          <Route path="/loginpage" exact component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path="/logout" exact component={LoginPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for. Thank you very much.